# How to programmatically create a list of Google Apps Script projects owned by me?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides, google-apps-script-api

Google Apps Scripts projects could be standalone, bounded to Google apps (Docs, Sheets), Web Apps or Google Sites gadgets. How could I find all the projects owned by me from a single point?

The [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file), [Class Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document), [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), [Class Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide) and [Class Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site) from Apps Script doesn't include a method to know if the corresponding container has a Script project bounded to them.

Only standalone Script projects are shown in Google Drive.

Update:

Nowadays (2018) it's possible to find all the Apps Script projects, bounded and standalone, owned by oneself on https://script.google.com and it's possible to access these projects programmatically through [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) but I don't know how to use it to create a list of projects owned by me.

[clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) has the command [clasp list](https://github.com/google/clasp#list) but it list only the 10 most recent projects.

Reference

- [The Apps Script Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard)

Related Q&A

- [I have scripts in one of spreadsheet document and cannot locate the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615090/1595451)
- [No scripts found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50289591/1595451)

Comment: I've filed a Feature Request that would extend the App Script API to support exactly such behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117105106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not good way to find all script OWNED by you because as you pointed out searching drive will only return standalone scripts. You can find all scripts Authorized by you though and revoke permissions on them.

Under Drive settings: Manage Apps.

or

Also under you google Account Settings->Account permissions
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Comment: The 2nd link is the one you want

Comment: Manage Apps in Google Drive settings only third party apps connected from the Chrome Web Store with Google Drive. In Account Settings->Account permissions there is a list of the apps that are authorized to access the account information. This is more helpful as it include both third party apps and the account owned apps but I'm not sure if this list Google Sites gadgets.

Comment: Ah yes. I often see my own scripts in manage apps as I usually integrate them with drive.