# I have scripts in one of spreadsheet document and cannot locate the script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Here's I got this email everyday since I created way before a timer based notification of events. I want to delete the script but I cannot found inside the spreadsheet. What I did, I deleted the file itself and empty the trash. Still I got the google failure notification even the host file was not exist. Anyone knows how to remove/report this problem.

> Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: spreadsheet_sms_notifier
>
> Your script, spreadsheet_sms_notifier, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
>   the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
>   future failure notifications, click here.
>
> Summary:
>
> Error Message Count Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   275 
>   Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End 2/4/18 8:19
>   AM    sendsms Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  2/4/18 8:19 AM 2/4/18 8:20 AM   sendsms Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  2/4/18 8:20 AM 2/4/18
>   8:21 AM   sendsms Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  2/4/18 8:21 AM ... ..

Comment: The email message includes "click here". Have you click on it?

Comment: It says "forbidden"..

Answer (score 0):

As you get a "forbidden" error message (mentioned in a comment) perhaps the email notification refers to an add-on. Try to uninstall it.

Another thing to try is to remove the associated trigger. From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

> To review all of the triggers that are associated with your Google
>   account and disable the triggers you no longer need, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Open the script editor by opening any script or visiting https://script.google.com.
> 2. Click **Edit > All your triggers**. If you just created a new script, the script editor will prompt you to give the script a name
>      first.
> 3. A dialog will list every simple or installable trigger that is associated with your account. From this dialog, it is not possible to
>      determine which script uses a given trigger, but if you recognize the
>      function name for an installable trigger and know that you don't need
>      the trigger anymore, you can delete the trigger by clicking the **X**
>      icon to the left of the function name.  Simple triggers like
>      `onOpen()` cannot be disabled from this dialog; instead, you must edit
>      the appropriate script and remove or rename the `onOpen()` function.

Comment: I tried this before I ask this question since I cannot found the script. There was nothing there in https://script.google.com. I opened all Monitor Projects, My projects, All Projects, Share with me, Trash, Executions and also Settings menu if there were hidden but there was none. In addition, I dont have any add-on installed in the spreadsheet document.

Comment: @altyne maybe you are looking at the wrong account.

Comment: Yes I have 5-6 google mail accounts (Thanks for pointing that). I observed if you select the executions (menu item); the account will switch to default (primary) account (might a bug?). Thus, the events will not be shown. I found the offending events in one account and open the script it says "404. The requested URL was not found in the server. That's all we know."