# No scripts found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have multiple Apps scripts running on google classic web sites. As of today 11/5/18 when I try to access the code I get a "No scripts found" message. If I create & save a new script I can write the code, but if I leave & return the script is no longer there. This is already causing me serious problems.

Comment: Please use the issue tracker, this site is not Google.

Answer (score 1):

Try locating your scripts on the Apps Script home page.

https://script.google.com/home

Here you will find all the scripts that you have created from your account irrespective of their location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the scripts, which has enabled be to track down the real problem - SitesApp.getActivePage() is now returning the wrong page (Home page) & as loads of these apps need to know which page they are on to work all our users are having serious problems & our public site is displaying gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the corresponding issue on the official Issue Tracker:

[Unable to view or modify Apps Scripts associated with Google Sites Classic; new scripts not properly associated with site](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79574626)

The workaround to access the script is to look for the script on https://script.google.com as was mentioned on [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289724/1595451)